# adjusted binomial test with correlation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

I am using this binomial test:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/binom.test.html

Are you aware of an implementation of an adjusted binomial test which takes into account correlation between events (e.g. defaults or other outcomes)?

Comment: What are defaults?

Comment: In this particular example I am analysing probabilities of defaults but it could be any event/outcome...